# Why does Wolfram Alpha give me the Taylor series for $\int \sin^2{x} \, dx$ in Big-O Notation?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

When I ask Wolfram Alpha to compute the integral of $\sin^2{x}$ with respect to $x$, one of the results it gives me is a Taylor series, but it includes a $O(x^8)$ term. What does it mean?

Taylor Series about $x=0$:

$$\frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^5}{15} + \frac{2x^7}{315} + O(x^8)$$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+sin%5E2(x)

Comment: It simply means that the series is truncated at that point. (Here terms with exponent $9$ or higher are omitted)

Comment: Look up Big O notation and Taylor's Theorem on Wikipedia.

Comment: If you input "series representation $\cdots$" or just "series $\cdots$", you might get the complete series.

Comment: As Peter said, this is a result of truncation. The actual Taylor series is infinitely long.  So the system gives you the first three terms and tells you that the rest of the series, which it didn't show you, is $O(x^8)$, i.e., is bounded by a constant times $x^8$ when $x$ is near $0$.

Comment: In the same box with its answer, Wolfram alpha gave me a link to its explanation of the big-O notation.

Comment: @Peter So does $O(x^8)$ just mean "and the other parts which grow faster than $x^8$"?

Comment: An $x^8$-term could occur as well (which is not the case here), so the other terms are of the form $a\cdot x^n$ with integer $n\ge 8$.

Comment: @Peter So are you just supposed to intuit what the rest of the terms are from the first few (just like you can tell that the next terms of $5,10,15$ are $20,25...$)? Because, as I understand it, the next term could be like, $x!$ or something which grows faster than $x^8$.

Comment: Correct, in general you cannot know what the next exponent is. But here,  it is clear that $\sin^2(x)$ contains exactly the even powers (starting with $2$) , so the antiderivate must contain exactly the odd powers (Starting with $3$)